# Nvidia Optimus available in Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have a lenovo U430p with a 730m nvidia card in it, as well as the intel HD from the motherboard.
I'm not a HUGE gamer, but I do like to play. I was wondering if by now, Nvidia optimus is already supported in Ubuntu.

By this I mean, out of the box, to be able to switch between graphics without having to log off, log on.

Thanks

Comment: Nope. There is Bumblebee, but... **General rule of thumb is to stay FAR away from laptops with Optimus.**

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16136/how-to-switch-between-gpus

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box? No. However, you can get the Nvidia Optimus to work through a project called 'Bumblebee'.

Here are installation instructions on the ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to install proprietary Nvidia drivers. An application called "nvidia settings" is also installed in addition to the drivers while this installation is going on.

When you want to switch to the Nvidia GPU, you have to open this application, go to "PRIME profiles" tab, and choose the GPU you desire to use.

It is not recommended to download the driver from Nvidia website. Installing the driver with command line is highly recommended:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Or you can install the one that works with you card the best:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

etc.

Although this'll not work as "optimus" as we understand. There's no dynamic switching between GPUs using this method. You choose a GPU, and it stays on always, until you switch back to the other one.